# GLFW3 and GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3, glfw

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and as I am learning OpenGL 3.3 I thought best to use

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

to force 'intellisense' to not even show old depreciated functions such as glVertex2f etc...

However the inclusion of said #define prevents any gl* functions from showing up. Even glViewport is undefined. When attempting to compile a simple application I get among many errors

```
error C3861: 'glViewport': identifier not found
```

glcorearb.h is my include files path though, downloaded from http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/GL/glcorearb.h only yesterday.

I might be doing something completely wrong here. But here is my full source code...

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB

// Include GLFW3
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

//Error Callback - Outputs to STDERR
static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fputs(description, stderr);
}

//Key Press Callback
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

int main(){

    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    // Initialise GLFW
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        fputs("Failed to initialize GLFW\n", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 2); // 2x antialiasing
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // We want OpenGL 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //We don't want the old OpenGL

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Test", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        float ratio;
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float)height;

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClearColor(0.5f, 0.7f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: While it doesn't apply to `glViewport()`, On windows you generally cannot rely on OpenGL 2+ functions being directly exposed by the graphics driver; you must use `wglGetProcAddress()` to retrieve a function pointer for each function you use.  Technically these dynamically loaded addresses may even differ for different contexts created by the same process and/or thread.  Tools like GLEW exist to simplify things, hiding these function pointers behind macros.

Comment: Also, `glcorearb.h` should be located in a `GL` subdirectory of one of the paths in your project's `$(IncludePath)`.  See [here](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html) for details.  It's not clear if this is where you actually have it placed.

Comment: It is located inside a `GL` directory. If I remove `#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB`, `glfw3.h` includes `gl.h` instead of `glcorearb.h`, but that exposes pre-OpenGL 3 functions.

Comment: I tried using GLEW previously but that exposes everything as well... maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree. Maybe I should be looking at a way to force GLEW to only expose OpenGL 3.3+

Comment: You also need `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` to get `glcorearb.h` to define function prototypes.  But you should only expect the GL 1.x ones to work on windows

Comment: OpenGL 3.x/4.x and OpenGL 1.x/2.x are not mutually exclusive.  For example, `glViewport` is GL 1.0, but it still exists in the GL 4.4 spec.  With `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` and `glcorearb.h` included you should have only the 1.x functions defined which are not deprecated, but you will still need to use `wglGetProcAddress()` for newer functions.

Comment: One last note, if you do end up using GLEW, it has issues with core profile contexts, so you may want to switch to compatibility profile.  Additionally, while core profile is good for learning modern OpenGL, the old fixed pipeline stuff can be extremely helpful in certain cases, like debug overlays.